# Replace footer page number using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a footer extracted out using regex from a PDF. The footer example is as below

```
footer_text = 'company name. (ABC) Q1 2020 Here is some text 01-Jan-2019   1-888-1234567   www.company.com  2 Copyright 2001-2019 some relevant text here'
```

I want to find this string across all my text and replace it with a space since I dont need this in the middle of my text extraction. However I have the page number inbetween the text which changes each time so it is not a simple find and replace. I am able to find the page number using

```
result = re.search(r"\s[\d]\s", footer_text)
```

But I dont know how to replace this 2 with any number during my find and replace. Any pointers?

Comment: First, your regex would only find a page number that had a single digit, which might be OK if you know that you never have more than 9 pages. But I don't see in `footer_text` anything that would match your regex (by the way, `'\s\d\s'` is sufficient -- you don't need `[]`), Not a great example.

Comment: Yes, this is from the second page - I am only using this to retrieve the footer at the start of the code. I want to replace it in all other places (pages 100+) with an empty space. The problem is everything about the footer is the same except for the page number. How do I find the footer with varying page numbers?

Comment: Yes, but you have  \*\*2\*\*, which is clearly not exactly a number separated by spaces.

Comment: I see what you are now. I added the ** to highlight it as bold. It does have spaces in front and back. I will change it

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that footer text does contain something that matches r'\s\d+\s` (I am allowing for page numbers >= 10), then first you want to create a regex by replacing the page number with the regex that matches it:

```
regex = re.sub(r'\\ \d+\\ ', r'\s\d+\s', re.escape(footer_text))
```

Now you can match any footer regardless of page number. The code then is:

```
>>> import re
...
... footer_text = 'company name. (ABC) Q1 2020 Here is some text 01-Jan-2019 1-888-1234567 www.company.com 11 Copyright 2001-2019some relevant text h
... ere'
...
... regex = re.sub(r'\\ \d+\\ ', r'\s\d+\s', re.escape(footer_text))
... replacement = ' ' # a single space (should this instead be '' for an empty string?)
...
... some_text = "abc" + footer_text + "def"
... print(regex)
... print(some_text)
... print(re.sub(regex, replacement, some_text))
...
company\ name\.\ \(ABC\)\ Q1\s\d+\sHere\ is\ some\ text\ 01\-Jan\-2019\ 1\-888\-1234567\ www\.company\.com\s\d+\sCopyright\ 2001\-2019some\ relevant\ text\ here
abccompany name. (ABC) Q1 2020 Here is some text 01-Jan-2019 1-888-1234567 www.company.com 11 Copyright 2001-2019some relevant text heredef
abc def
```

**For simpler copying:**

```
import re

footer_text = 'company name. (ABC) Q1 2020 Here is some text 01-Jan-2019 1-888-1234567 www.company.com 11 Copyright 2001-2019some relevant text here'

regex = re.sub(r'\\ \d+\\ ', r'\s\d+\s', re.escape(footer_text))
replacement = ' ' # a single space (should this instead be '' for an empty string?)

some_text = "abc" + footer_text + "def"
print(regex)
print(some_text)
print(re.sub(regex, replacement, some_text))
```

Comment: The regex is printing as 'company name. (ABC) Q1 2020 Here is some text 01-Jan-2019   1-888-1234567   www.company.com \s\d+\sCopyright 2001-2019some relevant text here' and isnt finding and replacing some_text when some_text has 11 there for example. 

footer_some_text = 'company name. (ABC) Q1 2020 Here is some text 01-Jan-2019   1-888-1234567   www.company.com  11 Copyright 2001-2019some relevant text here'
some_text = "abc" + footer_some_text + "def"

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot duplicate the results of my sample program?

Comment: Yes, the regex replacement isnt working in my code when the page number is different.

Comment: I see where I went astray. After I did `re.escape(footer_text)`, which is necessary in case the text has characters that have special meaning to a regular expression and therefore need to be escaped, it replaced the string '  11 ' with `\\ 11\\ ', which was unexpected (and unnecessary). So my replacement was not working. It should be OK now.